# Laravel Form Model Vinculación de relaciones uno a uno

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo una relación de  uno a uno (cliente-empresa), y no logro mostrar los datos de la empresa que le pertenece a un cliente en mi formulario de edicion. 
Solo consigo mostrar los datos del cliente(nombre, apellido, telefono, etc).

No estoy seguro si mi error esta en mi controlador o en la forma de enlazar mi formulario mediante la relacion.??

Estoy intentando esto lo cual me trae solo los datos del cliente.

->modelo cliente:

```
 public function company()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Company::class);
    }
```

->modelo company

```
 public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }
```

->mi controlador ClientController método edit:

```
  $client = Client::with('company')->findOrFail($id); 

  return view('admin.customers.partials.form', compact('client'));
```

->mi formulario form-model (laravel collective)
estos son los campos de la tabla company que tienen relacion con un cliente y no logro que los datos se muestren en mi formulario...

```
{!! Form::model($client, [
    'route' => $client->exists ? ['admin.customers.update', $client->id] : 'admin.customers.store',   
    'method' => $client->exists ? 'PUT' : 'POST'
]) !!}


            <div class="form-group">              
               {!! Form::label('name_company', 'Nombre') !!}                    
               {!! Form::text('name_company', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name_company']) !!}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('cuit', 'Cuit') !!}              
                {!! Form::text('cuit', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'cuit']) !!}               
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('web', 'Web') !!}                
                {!! Form::text('web', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'web']) !!}                
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('phone_company', 'Telefono') !!}                
                {!! Form::text('phone_company', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'phone_company']) !!}            
            </div>
```

->mi ruta:

```
Route::get('customers/{client}/edit',    'ClientController@edit')->name('admin.customers.edit');
```

¡¡Les agradezco su ayuda!!!

Answer (score 0):

controlador ClientController metodo edit:

```
$company = Company::with('client')->findOrFail($id);
$client = $company->client;
return view('admin.customers.partials.form', compact('client'));
```

puede ser que cliente te lo jale con `lista` en ese caso usa

```
$client = $company->client[0]
```

Comment: recien intente con lo que me indicaste pero me sigue trallendo los datos del cliente. y con esto me arroja un error $client = $company->client[0]: ```ErrorException: Trying to get property &#039;exists&#039; of non-object ```

Comment: entonces devuelve `compact('company')` y en tu vista imprimes `{{$company}}` debe estar con todos los datos incluido un nuevo parametro que diga `client` en donde estan tus datos de cliente

Comment: no te preocupes por relacionar tus tablas, `Laravel de encarga de eso` de la forma que vas trabajando, en caso de `id` diferentes, incluso en las relaciones, tendrias que definir  `return $this->hasOne("\App\Company","client_id","id");` o viceversa

Comment: `ORM` funciona de esa forma, en todo caso quitas `with('client')` ya no te jalará todo los datos del cliente, y empesarias a usa `DB::select()` en donde al igual que las consulas `SQL` escogeras solo lo que quieres ver

Comment: recien probe de imprimir company a mi vista y ahora me trae los datos de la empresa y no del cliente. es raro creo q se debe poder con eloquent.

Comment: cambia el `Client::class` por `\App\Client`